# Simplifying a finite double summation $\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^nf(n-ij)$ with both indexes over the same range

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Is there a way to simplify or reduce a double summation of of the form

$$\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^nf(n-ij)$$

where $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $n$ is a positive integer?

It seems to me that I need an explicit formula that enumerates the set of ${ij}$ for a given $n$, but I could be wrong. Maybe summation by parts?

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Assuming you have the convention that $f(k)=0$ when $k\le0$, the double sum is just $\sum_{1\le k\le n} f(k)\tau(n-k)$, where $\tau(m)$ is the number of positive divisors of $m$. I doubt it can be simplified any further.

Comment: You’ll need to do something about your indices because $n-ij <0$ for $i,j> \sqrt{n}$ if $n>1$, but you required a codomain for $f$ of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Thanks both. @adfriedman, I've adjusted the question.